# The ability to use the app only in a specific region (only using a code)

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play

I develop applications in AndroidStudio. For the first time in my life, I faced a problem - I was asked to make the application possible for use only within ONE country. I've thought all my life that this is configurable via the Google Play Console, but I've been told that it's not. Maybe someone knows how to implement such a restriction using a code only? Mb some changes in a gradle files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Locale to get the current country of users.

```
val locale = context.resources.configuration.locales.get(0).country
```

And you can make a request to a server to know users' countries.
For example, you can try: https://ipinfo.io/country

This is not an all-time work solution, but it's worth trying.

Comment: "resources" is not available in Java. What should i use instead of it?

Comment: Ah, it's `context.getResources().getConfiguration()....`. Sorry, I worte in kotlin